# debian 9 Ставится mariadb вместо mysql

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

При попытке установить MySQL сервер ставится MariaDB.

Хостер ставил свои ссылки на репозитории, я их заменил на эти:

```
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main

deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
```

Но все равно при запросе `apt-get install mysql-server` мне предлагают установить MariaDB. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: После обновление списка нужно выполнить сначала команду `apt-get update`

Comment: А зачем это исправлять?)

Comment: @andreymal Думаю, что автор вопроса новичек в мире GNU/Linux, либо не знал о марии :)))

Comment: @Anatol ,я  делал apt-get update.,@ andreymal меня не устраивает mariadb , на сколько я знаю InnoDB дает максимальное быстродействие. и на сколько я знаю, maridb не использует InnoDB

Comment: @Drop вас обманули, MariaDB использует InnoDB

Comment: @andreymal, буду знать, спасибо.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В Debian "stretch" MySQL 5.5 (которая была в Jessie) заменили на MariaDB, которая [бинарно совместима с MySQL 5.5](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/moving-from-mysql-to-mariadb-in-debian-9/). Легко убедиться что старый MySQL от Oracle [есть только в oldstable](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mysql-server-5.5).

Вы ничего не теряете при переходе на MariaDB, которую, кстати, разрабатывает исходный автор MySQL. Получаете исправленные баги и поддержку от дистрибутива и разработчиков.

Если же вам категорически нужно (почему?) чтобы у вас были именно MySQL от Oracle, то это тоже можно сделать. Скачиваете [файл установщика](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/), [затем](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install):

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_*_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Готово.

Comment: Верно! Большинство дистрибутивов перешло на марию.

Comment: Стоит отметить, что между MySQL и MariaDB заметная разница уже есть, например, у них разные реализации поддержки хранения JSON

Comment: @andreymal всё так, но это не касается версии 5.5, которая была в Jessie и с которой автор вопроса делает апгрейд